# Terraform resource generate multiple key_pair with modules

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to utilize terraform modules and am having issues with key creation. I want to generate a new aws_key_pair for each run of my module. I am receiving

aws_key_pair.default: Error import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'keyname' already exists.

I would like to generate a new key (with a different name) for each run of the module but am lost as to how to achieve this.

I have in variables.tf

```
variable "key_pair_name" {
  description = "EC2 Key pair name"
  default = ""
}
```

and in resources.tf

```
resource "key_pair" "default"
  key_name = "keyname"
  public_key = "${file("${var.key_path}")}"
```

Which generates the first key fine. When module runs it will try to  recreate the same key again which already exists. I want it to create a second, third and so on key named seperately ie: keyname1, keyname2, keyname3 or a random string.

I am trying

```
resource "random_id" "key_pair_name" {
  name = {
    key_name = "${random_id.key_name}"
  }

  byte_length = 8
}
```

I am starting this off from a simple main.tf

```
module "one" {
  source = "/modules/test-example"
```

Comment: Do you have an other tf file that calls your module?

Comment: yes just a simple "main.tf"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why would you want to keep uploading the same public key over and over but naming it different things? How are you intending to refer to it later if it has a random name?

Answer (score 1):

### Writting the module

In your `variable.tf`:

```
variable "key_pair_names" {
    description = "EC2 Key pair names"
    default = [
        "keyname1",
        "keyname2"
    ]
}
```

In your `resources.tf`:

```
resource "key_pair" "default" {
    count = "${length(var.key_pair_names)}"
    key_name = "${element(var.key_pair_names, count.index)}"
    public_key = "${file("${element(var.key_pair_names, count.index)}")}"
}
```

**NB: the name of the local file needs to be the same than the remote key pair created**

### To override the variables

- If you are running terraform directly in that directory, run:

  ```
  terraform apply -var-file=terraform.tfvars
  ```

  With the `terraform.tfvars:

  ```
  key_pair_names = [
      "keyname1",
      "keyname2",
      "keyname3"
  ]
  ```
- If your are using the module from an other `main.tf` file:

  ```
  module "key_pair" {
      path = "path/to/module"

      key_pair_names = [
          "keyname1",
          "keyname2",
          "keyname3"
      ]
  }
  ```

Comment: getting an "unexpected token while parsing list: IDENT" from variables.tf line "keyname1,

Comment: I might have missed the quotes. I edited the answer to add them.

Comment: thank you i had found that...getting a "key_pair.default: resource count can't reference variable: key_pair_names"

Comment: I updated the answer with the var prefix for the variables if you haven't already done it

Comment: was looking into that have added now and init passes however plan fails with  "no such file or directory in ${file("${element(var.key_pair_names, count.index)}")}

Comment: As I mentionned in the answer: the name of the local file needs to be the same than the remote key pair created. So you should have existing files that matches the name passed through the variables

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has this problem I was able to solve this using terraform random_id

```
resource "random_id" "keypair" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "keypair" "default" {
  name = "${random_id.keypair.hex}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve unique keyname at every run, you can use `uuid` function in terraform (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#uuid-)

You can define your codeblock as

```
resource "key_pair" "default"
  key_name = "keyname-${uuid()}"
  public_key = "${file("${var.key_path}")}"
```

But what are you trying to achieve with different keypair against a public key?